# insert text-resource into jsf page

Tags: jsf, rest

there's a RESTful service which is Producing `text/plain` and I want to add that content into my JSF page. Is that possible? Is there a tag for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using JSP as view technology, you can use the [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`<c:import>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) for this. It's as simple as

```
<c:import url="http://example.com/service" />
```

It however doesn't run in sync with JSF as you'd expect from the coding. Also, this is not supported in Facelets. So if you want to render/display it conditionally (and thus run in sync with JSF) or are using Facelets, then you'll have to do this in the managed bean. To start, you can use [`java.net.URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and consorts to get content from an URL.

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://example.com/service").openStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"); // You may want to verify charset based on response headers.
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int data; (data = reader.read()) > -1;) {
    builder.append((char) data);
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Put this in the constructor or action method, depending on the conditions it needs to execute. You can however also wrap this all in flavor of a standalone custom/composite component or EL function.

#### Related questions:

- [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)